# Re-try is happening for already passed test also along with the failed tests while trying to achieve data provider concept in webdriver.io

Tags: webdriver-io

Am using webdriver.io with jasmine framework. In my project am trying to achieve data provider concept. I hava achieved it using for each loop and when i try to retry the failed tests, passed test is also getting retried along with the failed tests. Is there any solution to fix this issue